# Add multiple polyline attributes to one polygon layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

[image]
I am trying to join multiple polyline attributes that intersect with a buffer polygon. In the picture below you can see buffers i have created which are actually intersection buffers. Around it are the poly-lines which are streets with information about traffic volumes. I want to add all the traffic volume information to the polygon. For example: intersection buffer 312 is connecting four streets with traffic volumes of 250, 3500 and 2600 (see image below). Intersection buffer 176 has two streets intersecting to it with traffic volumes of 1600 and 800. I want to populate all the street volumes (that are intersecting with the buffer) in the attribute table of the intersection buffer.

I have tried to use spatial join tool, plus using the usual join-relates to achieve this but its giving me only one traffic volume value in the attribute table. How can I have all the traffic volumes of the street intersecting with the buffer in its attributes table?

Comment: Do you have the Sum box checked?

Answer (score 1):

We recently went through this same process trying to automate some traffic volume info.  Here are the steps we followed:

1. Create Buffers at intersections (each has unique ID)
2. Spatial Join the Traffic Volume Info to the Buffers (one to many)
3. Dissolve by the unique ID with the stat field ["Current_Volume", "SUM"]